# How to add a proxy to grpcurl requests?

Tags: proxy, grpc, http-proxy, hoverfly

I have a service which serves requests over gRPC. I'm using Hoverfly for mocking that service in my tests. Ordinarily, I use `grpcurl` for gRPC requests on my terminal. But for these tests, I need to add a proxy to the `gRPC` requests so they can hit Hoverfly instead of the service and a mocked response is delivered.

For regular HTTP requests, I can do this by adding a `--proxy` flag to `curl` like

```
curl --proxy http://localhost:8500 http://time.jsontest.com
```

Is there a way to do this for `gRPC` requests (preferably via `grpcurl` but wouldn't mind using another tool)?

Comment: Might be worth asking a question on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl

Comment: `grpcurl` will take a while to implement it: https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/issues/166